# How can I turn this into an AngularJs Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a select list that I am populating with ng-options. It also has a "default" selected item that kind of acts like a "placeholder" since  lists don't have an actual "placeholder" attribute.

However, what I wanted to accomplish was to have only that very first  (the placeholder value) have a lighter font color than all the rest of the options in the select list very similar to that of the lighter font a placeholder attribute in a text input has.

I got this to work but without writing a Directive. I'd like to port this code over to a Directive so that it more conforms to the "Angular Way" and is more reusable across my site.

Any help would be really appreciated! See below for code:

**The HTML:**

```
<select  
    ng-model="priority"
    id="priority" name="priority"
    class="span7"
    required
    ng-options="p.Description for p in priorities"
    ng-class="appliedClass()">

    <option value="" selected>select priority</option>

</select>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.select-placeholder {
    color: #999;
}
```

**The JS:**

```
    /*
        Watches the 'priority' select list for changes
    */
    $scope.$watch('priority', function(value) {

        // value of the <option> element from the select list
        var selectedValue = value;

        // applies the 'select-placeholder' css class to ng-class
        // if the selected item is the default (placeholder) item.
        $scope.appliedClass = function() {

            if (selectedValue === undefined) {
                return 'select-placeholder';

            }

        };

    });
```

Comment: its better you give a try first using angular documentation http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive and if you have some problem the ask the problem again

Comment: Anybody else care to answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option if the user really has to enter a value would be to add the `required` html5 attribute and style based on the `:invalid` rule:

```
/* style based on invalid */
select:invalid { color: red }

/* so drop-down items don't inherit color */
select:invalid option { color: black; }
```

html:

```
<select required>
```

You *could* do your styling all in css based on value, but the value attribute isn't set when the value property changes:

```
/* style based on value */
select[value=""] {
    color: #aaa;
}

/* so drop-down items don't inherit color */
select option {
    color: black;
}

/* if you want the style in the drop-down list too */
select option:nth-child(1) {
    color: #aaa;
}
```

To fix that you could use jQuery to set the value attribute based on the value property ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/Bh9pz/1/)):

```
$('#priority').attr("value", $('#priority').val())
    .change(function() { $(this).attr("value", this.value); });
```

Or an angular directive ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/R4vK3/5/)):

```
app.directive("setValueAttribute", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.attr('value', element.val());
            element.on('change', function(e) {
                var that = angular.element(this);
                that.attr('value', that.val());
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Wow! thanks so much for taking the time to explain it and demonstrate it so well! Take care!

Comment: Jason, I'm looking through it again, and it works great but I still don't quite understand how exactly. How does it know to set the "placeholder" value to gray defined in the css above it? Thx again!

Comment: `select[value=""]` sets the color to gray when the value attribute of the select is empty.  The option elements when the box is dropped down are separate but they inherit that so you need to make them black with another rule, then the third rule colors the first drop-down option using `nth-child`.

Comment: Thanks Jason, sorry I should have been more clear, I was referring to the Directive you wrote. The directive doesn't seem to check for an empty option value...how is this working exactly? Thanks again and I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Ah, the directive simply copies whatever the value property is to the value attribute.  The value property that contains what the user selected is not available as a css selector.  You could call the attribute "data-my-attribute" and use that in the css as an attribute selector if you wanted, or you could change the directive to add a css class if the value is empty and remove it if there is something there.